# How to fix the Dropping Close since the SSL connection is already closing error in spray

Tags: scala, akka, spray, scala-2.11, spray-client

I’m making a call to an API, but most of the time I keep getting an error: “**Dropping Close since the SSL connection is already closing**” and “**Premature connection close (the server doesn't appear to support request pipelining)**.” Like 90% of the time I get that error, meaning: on very rare occasions the query does return the data it supposed to.

*To make sure this wasn’t the API’s server issue, I replicate the same query using Node.js (Express and Request libs) and it works every time. It makes me almost sure is a spray bug*.

**Here's an example of the code**:

```
case class MyClass(user: String, pass: String)

class MyActor extends Actor {
  import spray.client.pipelining._
  import spray.http.BasicHttpCredentials
  import spray.http.{HttpRequest,HttpResponse}
  import scala.concurrent.Future

  import context.dispatcher

  def receive = {
    case myClass: MyClass => {
      val credentials: BasicHttpCredentials = BasicHttpCredentials(myClass.user, myClass.pass)
      val url: String = "https://myApi?params=values"
      val request: HttpRequest = Get(url) ~> addCredentials(credentials)
      val pipeline = sendReceive
      val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(request)
      val finalRes: Future[String] = response.map{ r =>
        println(r)
        r.entity.asString
      }
      finalRes pipeTo sender
    }
  } // end receive
} //end Actor
```

**Error Detail**:

```
04/01 10:19:05 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] a.i.TcpOutgoingConnection - Attempting connection to ...
04/01 10:19:05 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] a.i.TcpOutgoingConnection - Connection established to ...
04/01 10:19:05 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] s.c.c.HttpClientConnection - Connected to ...
04/01 10:19:05 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] s.c.c.HttpHostConnectionSlot - Connection to ... established, dispatching 1 pending requests
04/01 10:19:05 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] s.c.c.HttpClientConnection - now monitoring Actor[akka://on-spray-can/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/5]
04/01 10:19:05 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] s.c.c.HttpHostConnectionSlot - Dispatching GET request to /api?params=values across connection Actor[akka://on-spray-can/user/IO-HTTP/group-0/4]
04/01 10:19:05 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] s.c.c.HttpHostConnectionSlot - now monitoring Actor[akka://on-spray-can/user/IO-HTTP/group-0/4]
04/01 10:19:06 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] s.c.c.HttpClientConnection - Dropping Close since the SSL connection is already closing
04/01 10:19:06 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] s.c.c.HttpClientConnection - Connection was PeerClosed, awaiting TcpConnection termination...
04/01 10:19:06 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] a.i.TcpOutgoingConnection - stopped
04/01 10:19:06 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] s.c.c.HttpClientConnection - TcpConnection terminated, stopping
04/01 10:19:06 WARN [on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] s.c.c.HttpHostConnectionSlot - Premature connection close (the server doesn't appear to support request pipelining) in response to GET request to /myApi?params=values with 1 retries left, retrying...
04/01 10:19:06 DEBUG[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] s.c.c.HttpClientConnection - stopped
```

**And I was able to reproduce the error in all of these versions**:

```
spray 1.0.1; akka 2.0.5; scala 2.9.3
spray 1.2.1; akka 2.2.4; scala 2.10.1
spray 1.3.1; akka 2.3.0; scala 2.10.3
spray 1.3.2; akka 2.3.6; scala 2.11.4
spray 1.3.3; akka 2.3.9; scala 2.11.6
```

Comment: I'm seeing similar behaviour. In my case, spray can is trying to send my application actor a message but the PeerClosed message appears to gazump it and the message is dropped.

Comment: I posted the issue in spray.io google group as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/w0oeFC7eJ_s

Comment: I think that it is related either to the JVM that you have or SSL on the other side. Have you tried to use some API client and make an request? At least write, which JVM version do you use.

Comment: Is the server you are trying to connect akka-http based/spray-based server?
Check the akka-http config then in that case.

Answer (score 1):

as you said,

> To make sure this wasn’t the API’s server issue, I replicate the same
>   query using Node.js (Express and Request libs) and it works every
>   time. It makes me almost sure is a spray bug.

your code in scala send requests with HTTP pipelining feature, do you send the requests with HTTP pipelining feature while you testing with nodejs?

for error message:

> the server doesn't appear to support request pipelining

you should make sure:

1. please make sure that the server support the pipelining feature, and the pipelining feature is enable.
2. if there are proxies between your client and server(include reverse proxy), please make sure that the proxies support pipelining feature, and the pipelining feature is enable.

If you can't make sure the pipelining feature can be supported properly, you should not use it.

following resource may helpful:

> HTTP pipelining requires both the client and the server to support it.
>   HTTP/1.1 conforming servers are required to support pipelining. This
>   does not mean that servers are required to pipeline responses, but
>   that they are required not to fail if a client chooses to pipeline
>   requests.[7]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining

> HTTP pipelining is not activated by default in modern browsers:
>
> Buggy proxies are still common and these lead to strange and erratic
>   behaviors that Web developers cannot foresee and diagnose easily.
>   Pipelining is complex to implement correctly: the size of the resource
>   being transferred, the effective RTT that will be used, as well as the
>   effective bandwidth, have a direct incidence on the improvement
>   provided by the pipeline. Without knowing these, important messages
>   may be delayed behind unimportant ones. The notion of important even
>   evolves during page layout! HTTP pipelining therefore brings a
>   marginal improvement in most cases only. Pipelining is subject to the
>   HOL problem. For these reasons, pipelining has been superseded by a
>   better algorithm, multiplexing, that is used by HTTP/2.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Connection_management_in_HTTP_1.x$revision/1330814